# How to drag and drop multiple items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a grid created using a library in React and currently it drag and drops multiple items. What I am trying to achieve is to select items pressing the Ctrl key and drag and drop all selected item, but I am not sure how exactly this can be achieved. I tried saving all selected items in an array and passing it to the parent where the reorder logic is being held, but it doesn't work, how can I achieve this and drag and drop all selected items? Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Grid, GridColumn as Column } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
import { DragAndDrop } from '@progress/kendo-react-common';
import { DraggableRow } from './draggable-row';
import { Checkbox } from '@progress/kendo-react-inputs';
import { DragHandleCell } from './drag-handle-cell';
import products from './products.json';
import {
  groupBy,
  GroupDescriptor,
  GroupResult,
} from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { groupBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';

export const ReorderContext = React.createContext({
  reorder: () => {},
  dragStart: () => {},
});

const App = () => {
  const [gridData, setGridData] = React.useState(products);
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = React.useState(null);

  const reorder = (dataItem, direction) => {
    if (activeItem === dataItem) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(activeItem);

    let reorderedData = gridData.slice();
    let prevIndex = reorderedData.findIndex((p) => p === activeItem);
    let nextIndex = reorderedData.findIndex((p) => p === dataItem);
    reorderedData.splice(prevIndex, 1);
    reorderedData.splice(
      Math.max(nextIndex + (direction === 'before' ? -1 : 0), 0),
      0,
      activeItem || reorderedData[0]
    );
    setGridData(reorderedData);
  };

  const dragStart = (dataItem) => {
    setActiveItem(dataItem);
  };

  return (
    <ReorderContext.Provider
      value={{
        reorder: reorder,
        dragStart: dragStart,
      }}
    >
      <DragAndDrop>
        <Grid
          style={{
            height: '400px',
          }}
          data={gridData}
          dataItemKey={'ProductID'}
          rowRender={(row, rowProps) => (
            <DraggableRow elementProps={row.props} {...rowProps} />
          )}
        >
          <Column title="" width="80px" cell={DragHandleCell} />
          {/* <Column title="" width="80px" cell={CustomCell} /> */}
          <Column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="60px" />
          <Column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="250px" />
          <Column field="Category.CategoryName" title="CategoryName" />
          <Column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" width="80px" />
          <Column field="UnitsInStock" title="In stock" width="80px" />
        </Grid>
      </DragAndDrop>
    </ReorderContext.Provider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('my-app'));
```

and my draggable row:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ReorderContext } from './main';
import { useDraggable, useDroppable } from '@progress/kendo-react-common';
export const DraggableRow = (props) => {
  const [dropped, setDropped] = React.useState(false);
  const [dragged, setDragged] = React.useState(false);
  const [direction, setDirection] = React.useState(null);
  const [selectedItems] = React.useState([]);
  const [initial, setInitial] = React.useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });
  const { dragStart, reorder } = React.useContext(ReorderContext);
  const element = React.useRef(null);

  const handlePress = (event) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey == true) {
      element.current.style.color = 'red';
      selectedItems.push(props.dataItem);
    }
    setInitial({
      x: event.clientX - event.offsetX,
      y: event.clientY - event.offsetY,
    });
  };

  const handleDragStart = (event) => {
    if (
      !event.originalEvent.target ||
      !event.originalEvent.target.dataset.dragHandle
    ) {
      return;
    }

    setDragged(true);
    dragStart(props.dataItem);
  };

  const handleDrag = (event) => {
    if (!element.current || !dragged) {
      return;
    }

    element.current.style.transform = `translateY(${
      event.clientY - initial.y + event.scrollY
    }px)`;
  };

  const handleDragEnd = () => {
    setDragged(false);
    setDropped(false);
    setInitial({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
    });
  };

  const handleRelease = () => {
    if (!element.current) {
      return;
    }

    element.current.style.transform = null;
  };

  const handleDragEnter = () => {
    setDropped(true);
    setDirection(null);
  };

  const handleDragOver = (event) => {
    if (!element.current) {
      return;
    }

    const rect = element.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    setDirection(
      rect.top + rect.height / 2 <= event.pageY ? 'after' : 'before'
    );
  };

  const handleDragLeave = () => {
    setDropped(false);
    setDirection(null);
  };

  const handleDrop = () => {
    reorder(props.dataItem, direction);
    setDropped(false);
    setDirection(null);
  };

  useDraggable(
    element,
    {
      onPress: handlePress,
      onDragStart: handleDragStart,
      onDrag: handleDrag,
      onDragEnd: handleDragEnd,
      onRelease: handleRelease,
    },
    {
      autoScroll: dragged,
    }
  );
  useDroppable(element, {
    onDragEnter: handleDragEnter,
    onDragOver: handleDragOver,
    onDragLeave: handleDragLeave,
    onDrop: handleDrop,
  });
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {dropped && direction === 'before' && (
        <tr
          style={{
            outlineStyle: 'solid',
            outlineWidth: 1,
            outlineColor: 'red',
          }}
        />
      )}
      <tr
        {...props.elementProps}
        ref={element}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          userSelect: 'none',
          pointerEvents: dragged ? 'none' : undefined,
          opacity: dragged ? '0.8' : undefined,
        }}
      />
      {dropped && direction === 'after' && (
        <tr
          style={{
            outlineStyle: 'solid',
            outlineWidth: 1,
            outlineColor: 'red',
          }}
        />
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

And here is a working example of what I have so far:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cv2hnu-zttr7g?file=app/draggable-row.jsx

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, but does nobody know how to do this??

Comment: Perhaps with https://docs.dndkit.com